# How to solve this "NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined"?

Tags: gensim

I installed !pip install  atlas, !pip3 install -U spacy, then I run `x_train = [gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text) for text in text_train]` but it showed this name error. My train test split was `text_train = text_train[:10] y_train=y_train[:10] text_train`

Can anyone please help me to understand why genism is not working in my code?

`!pip3 install -U spacy`
`x_train = [gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text) for text in text_train]`
`text_train = text_train[:10] y_train=y_train[:10] text_train`

Comment: If you disagree with Python's claim that `gensim` is not defined - then please show us the line of code that you believe does define it.  Nothing like that is present in the fragment of code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

What is your environment? (The !-escapes make it seem like a notebook, but is it some remote cloud service or a local Jupyter install?)

Why are you sometimes using `pip` and other times using `pip3` to install things? (Those might be installing the packages into different environments, especially on a system with both Python2 and Python 3 installed. And, only one may be the right place to be available to your subsequent notebook code.)

Often, the running interpreter behind your *current* notebook won't notice new packages installed in its environment (as if by the !-escape shell commands) until after it is restarted. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I solved it by importing gensim after installing this. Thank you

Comment: Glad it's working! Even better than a thank-you when you get a good answer is to upvote and click the accept checkbox for the helpful answer. And, if you mistakenly write a comment in the wrong place – as with the other "answer" you added here – you can delete the mistake to leave the Q&A record more clear & useful for future readers.